# Mobile menu problems with Slicknav

Tags: jquery, html

Good day everyone. I am hoping you can help me with a problem. I am doing an SLP course with a University called UNISA, and the current thing I am learning is how to make a mobile menu, using a plugin called Slicknav. However, I am having trouble getting it to work. My webpage is not doing anything whenever I do as required by the website to get the plugin to work.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Experimentation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Experimentation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slicknav.css"/>
<script src="jquery.slicknav.min.js">
    $(function(){
        $('#menu').slicknav();
    });
    </script>
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('#menu').slicknav();
});
</script>
</script>

</head>

<body>

<header>
    <img src="youtube-square-logo-3F9D037665-seeklogo.com.png" height="60px" width="80px" alt="youtube_logo" id="rightimg">
    <img src="youtube-square-logo-3F9D037665-seeklogo.com.png" height="60px" width="80px" alt="youtube_logo" id="leftimg">
    <h2>Youtubers</h2>
    <h3>Wiki</h3>
</header>





<nav id="nav_bar">

    <ul>

        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PewdiePie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Markiplier</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jacksepticeye</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More Youtubers</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>






<aside id="youtubers">
    <h3>Most famous <br>Youtubers</h3><br>

    <h4>Pewdiepie</h4>
  <img src="http://images.techtimes.com/data/images/full/214602/pewdiepieemmys.jpg" height="100px"/>
    <br><hr><br>
    <h4>Markiplier</h4>
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/80/3d/56/803d568c2917e8a400c13325f146127d--the-guys-youtuber.jpg" height="150px"/>

    <br><hr><br>
    <h4>Jacksepticeye</h4>
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/98/35/88/98358846e093741f47afa06144d006f3--your-teacher-middle-fingers.jpg" height="100px" style="padding-bottom:2em;"/>



</aside>

<main>
    <h2>The job of youtubers</h2>

    <p>Since the start of Youtube, jobs known as content creatoris have risen to the surface, due to the existance of Youtube. By having ads played on the videos they upload, they are able to earn money simply by uploading videos. Many peopple have become famous because of this.</p> 
    <p>Some of the most well known of these are people like Pewdiepie, Markiplier and Jacksepticeye. They record "Lets Plays" where they record themselves playing and reacting to a gems many twists and turns</p>

    <p>This has also earned a lot of controversey due to the fact that people cannot understand why people would watch a person play a game instead of playing it for themselves. There are many reasons for this. Often, people would rather play the games themselves, but various circumstances may prevent them from doing so. Lack of time, lack of cash. Another possibility is that it is even a game they would not enjoy playing, but simply seeing another person react to it can bring enjoyment to these people</p>


</main>

<aside id="importlinks">
    <h2>Youtuber links</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Youtube</li>
        <li>Pewdiepie Channel</li>
        <li>Jacksepticeye Channel</li>
        <li>Markiplier Channel</li>
    </ul>





</aside>



<footer>

    <p>All rights co to their respective owners</p>

    <ul id="menu">

        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PewdiePie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Markiplier</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jacksepticeye</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More Youtubers</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

The website is simply one I created to test out everything I learn, so take whatever is said in the document with a grain of salt. I hope you can help me with this matter, as it is driving me up the wall with frustration!

Comment: Please tell me if you need anything else to answer the question

Comment: Hi Poseidon - I'm UNISA as well. Anyway you need to show your debugging info (Google developer console). And maybe be a little more clear on what needs to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Jquery problems:

It seems like you are missing a reference to JQuery.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" Integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Some advice:**

I would recommend placing your scripts (*in the correct order*) at the bottom of the `< body >` tag:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" Integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="jquery.slicknav.min.js" />
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#menu').slicknav();
    });
</script>
```

*Remember if slicknav has a dependency on Jquery you need to include it in your page.*

Good luck man.

PS: Also at UNISA.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your advice has answered my question. Just one more question. What do you mean by placing my scripts at the bottom of the body tag? They don't work then? Other than that, thanks for the help! You helped me here!

Comment: There is lots of literature on where to place your scripts. I'd suggest giving it a google!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jquery lib file. include it before SlickNav js file. Things will start work. and for styling purpose you can also use SlickNav  css[image] file.

Good Day!